# Accessing parameters of objects from a .each do block?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've searched extensively for this (maybe I'm searching it wrong), but I can't seem to find any answers on this.  My aim is to iterate through a bunch of comments in my database and output the info to my view.  Unfortunately, my `.each do` block does not seem to be working.

**models/comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :photo_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :photo
```

.

**controllers/photos_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @photos = Photo.all
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  @user_likes = user_likes(@photo.id)
  @comments = Comment.find_all_by_photo_id(@photo.id)
```

.

**views/photos/show.html.erb**

```
  <% if !@comments.blank? %>
    <% @comments.each do |c| %>
      <%= link_to c.user.name, c.user_id %><br />
      <%= c.content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

.

If I use `@comments.each do |c|, c.(anything)`, it will return nothing.  I've verified this in rails console as well.  However, `@comments.first.content` or `@comments.first.user.name` will return what I'm looking for.  Why does `.first` allow me to return **content** and **user** fields, but `.each do |c|` returns nothing?

Here's output from the rails console:

```
1.9.3-p385 :072 > @comments.each do |c|
1.9.3-p385 :073 >     c.content
1.9.3-p385 :074?>   end
 => [#<Comment id: 1, user_id: 8, photo_id: 27, content: "lalala", created_at: "2013-04-09 15:36:22", updated_at: "2013-04-09 15:36:22">, #<Comment id: 2, user_id: 8, photo_id: 27, content: "abcd", created_at: "2013-04-09 15:42:00", updated_at: "2013-04-09 15:42:00">, #<Comment id: 3, user_id: 8, photo_id: 27, content: "abadsf", created_at: "2013-04-09 15:58:33", updated_at: "2013-04-09 15:58:33">, #<Comment id: 4, user_id: 8, photo_id: 27, content: "asdf", created_at: "2013-04-09 15:59:12", updated_at: "2013-04-09 15:59:12">] 

1.9.3-p385 :075 > @comments.first.content
 => "lalala"
```

Comment: check the contents of `@comments` after the assignment inside the controller (f.e. with something like `raise @comments.inspect`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you posted from the console is normal:

- You are iterating over each comments (so that the `c` variable in the block contains a comment)
- Then you are just calling the attribute `content` on that instance without doing anything

So the output is the content of the variable `@comments`.
Now if you call `puts c.content` you will have what you're expecting.

Remarks:

1. If you're using Rails 3 (as mentioned by the tags of this question) you shouldn't use the `find_by_all_` helpers but the `where()` method (You should have a look at this **free** railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/202-active-record-queries-in-rails-3).
2. You should use the Rails relations so that instead of doing `Comment.find_all_by_photo_id(@photo.id)` you could do `@photo.comments`.
   You could then use this in your view:

```rb
<% if @photo.comments.present? %>
  <% @photo.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <%= link_to comment.user.name, comment.user_id %><br />
    <%= comment.content %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```